# Error in using perl references for arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I was trying to implement symbol table using hash table in perl. In the following code I created an array `@Table` whose elements are references to another array (whose elements are also array references). Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub getKey {
  my $name = $_[0];
  my $count = 0;
  my $key = 0;
  my $len = length ($name);
  while ($count < $len) {
    my $char = substr ($name, $count, 1);
    $key = 7 * $key + ord ($char);
    $count = $count + 1;
  }
  $key = $key % 20;
  return $key;
}
sub Define {
  (my $name, my $kind, my $type, my $Index, my $scope) = @_;
  my $key = getKey($name);
  print "key is $key\n";
  @$entry = ("$name", "$kind", "$type", "$Index", "$scope");
  unshift (@{$Table[$key]}, $entry);
  print "$name is stored at key $key it is of kind $kind, type $type, at Index $Index and scope $scope\n";
  print "entry is @$entry\n";
  my $i = 0;
  while ( $i < 20){
  print "[$i]--> @{$Table[$i]->[0]}\n"; $i++;}
  return;
}
our @Table;
my $i = 0;
while ($i < 20) {
  $Table[$i] = [];
  $i++;
}
Define ("x","field","int","0","0");
Define ("y","argument","int","0","1");
```

I wanted that whenever I define a new symbol by using subroutine `Define` I add the information about the type (for example type for symbol x is field) and kind (which is int for x) etc., in an array which will be pointed to by the element `$key` i.e. `$Table[$key]`of the array `@Table`. The key will be evaluated for the symbol (x or y) using subroutine `getKey`.The final array that is getting printed out as the output of the above code is :

```
[0]--> y argument int 0 1
[1]--> y argument int 0 1
[2]--> 
[3]--> 
[4]--> 
[5]--> 
[6]--> 
[7]--> 
[8]--> 
[9]--> 
[10]--> 
[11]--> 
[12]--> 
[13]--> 
[14]--> 
[15]--> 
[16]--> 
[17]--> 
[18]--> 
[19]-->
```

But I expected the output to be:

```
[0]--> x field int 0 0
[1]--> y argument int 0 1
[2]--> 
[3]--> 
[4]--> 
[5]--> 
[6]--> 
[7]--> 
[8]--> 
[9]--> 
[10]--> 
[11]--> 
[12]--> 
[13]--> 
[14]--> 
[15]--> 
[16]--> 
[17]--> 
[18]--> 
[19]-->
```

Why is the output different from expected?

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Perl has a perfectly good hash structure.  Are you supposed to be building your own using an array and hashing algorithm?

Comment: Agreed with @mob's comment. Please add `use strict; use warnings;` to the beginning of your script. It will force you to declare all your variables (especially `$entry`). Without it we'll be wasting our time looking for error, which can be found by perl compiler instantly. Also take a look at anonymous array references: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is in this line:

```
@$entry = ("$name", "$kind", "$type", "$Index", "$scope");
```

Because `$entity` variable is not defined it'll have global scope. So its value will remain the same between `Define(...)` calls. This is one of the reason why you should put `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of the script.

Here is what is happening:

- on first `Define(...)` call:

  - expression `@$entry = ...` will create anonymous array
  - save its reference into `$entry`
  - override first 5 elements of array with some values
  - then reference to that array will be put into first element of `@Table`
- on seconds call:

  - `$entity` is still pointing to same anonymous array (because it's global)
  - new values will be put into array
  - then reference to the same array will be put into second element of `@Table`
- now you have same reference in `@Table` twice and first values are overwritten by second run

To fix this you need to declare scope of `$entry` like this:

```
my $entry = [$name, $kind, $type, $Index, $scope];
```

I've used [anonymous array syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) `[...]`.

Comment: You don't need all of those quotes.